# KTable & LogAndContinueExceptionHandler

Tags: apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I have a very simple consumer from which I create a materialized view. I have enabled validation on my value object (throwing Constraintviolationexception for invalid json data). When I receive a value on which the validation fails, ***I exepct the value to logged & consumer should read the next offset as I have LogAndContinueExceptionHandler enabled***.

However LogAndContinueExceptionHandler is never invoked and consumePojo State transition from PENDING_ERROR to ERROR

Code

```
@Bean
    public Consumer<KTable<String, Pojo>> consume() {
        return values-> 
                values
                .filter((key, value) -> Objects.nonNull(key))
                .mapValues(value-> value, Materialized.<String, Pojo>as(Stores.inMemoryKeyValueStore("POJO_STORE_NAME"))
                .withKeySerde(Serdes.String())
                .withValueSerde(SerdeUtil.pojoSerde())
                .withLoggingDisabled())
                .toStream()
                .peek((key, value) -> log.debug("Receiving Pojo from topic with key: {}, and UUID: {}", key, value == null ? 0 : value.getUuid()));
    }
```

**Why is it that LogAndContinueExceptionHandler is not invoked in case of KTable?**

Note: If code is changed to KStreams then I see logging and records being skipped but with KTable not !!

Answer (score 0):

In order to handle exceptions not handled by Kafka Streams use the `KafkaStreams.setUncaughtExceptionHandler` method and `StreamsUncaughtExceptionHandler` implementation, this needs to return one of 3 available enumerations:

- REPLACE_THREAD
- SHUTDOWN_CLIENT
- SHUTDOWN_APPLICATION

and in your case REPLACE_THREAD is the best option, as you can see in [KIP-671](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-671%3A+Introduce+Kafka+Streams+Specific+Uncaught+Exception+Handler):

> ```
> REPLACE_THREAD:
>
> The current thread is shutdown and transits to state DEAD.
>
> A new thread is started if the Kafka Streams client is in state RUNNING or REBALANCING.
> For the Global thread this option will log an error and revert to shutting down the client until the option had been added
> ```

In Spring Kafka you can replace default `StreamsUncaughtExceptionHandler` by `StreamsBuilderFactoryBean`:

```java
    @Autowired
    void setMyStreamsUncaughtExceptionHandler(StreamsBuilderFactoryBean streamsBuilderFactoryBean) {
        streamsBuilderFactoryBean.setStreamsUncaughtExceptionHandler(exception -> StreamsUncaughtExceptionHandler.StreamThreadExceptionResponse.REPLACE_THREAD);
    }
```

Comment: Hello Pawel, The above code doesn't restart my consumer thread. The thread goes into ERROR STATE.  The exception occurs during deserialization of bytes to pojo object. I would like to skip this record and move to next offset LogAndContinueExceptionHandler functionality.

Comment: In the question you mention `Constraintviolationexception`. For deserialization errors you need to override `DeserializationExceptionHandler`

Comment: Apologies for the confusion, it exception `Constraintviolationexception` occured durig the deserialization the stream terminated instead of invoking `DeserializationExceptionHandler`.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem after looking at the logs carefully, I found that valueSerde for the Pojo, was showing useNativeDecoding (default being JsonSerde) due to this `DeserializationExceptionHandler` wasn't invoked and thread terminated.

Problem went away when I fixed the valueSerde in application.properties